# Why are there people with so many badges when there is a limited number of them?

Tags: support, badges

I have seen people with, for example, 90 gold badges.

However, I have seen the [Stack Badges collection](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) and there aren't so many gold badges.

How can they achieve this big number of badges? Is there anyone that you can get more than once?

Comment: If you get score of 1000 for a tag, you'll get [tag gold badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold).

Comment: Just take a look at the badges of that person: https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656?tab=badges.

Comment: @zondo Nice example haha ;)

Comment: Where does it say there is a limited number of badges?

Comment: @EJP In the link I provide, there is a limited number of **different** badges. But I didn't know you can get many badges more than once.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are many badges that you can get more than once. They have the following text in description:

> This badge can be awarded multiple times.

See for example [Great Answer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer).

Also, you can earn a gold tag badge for every tag that exists on Stack Overflow, when you have at least 200 non-community wiki answers with a total score of 1000 in that tag.

Comment: And the [Yearling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731) badge (not a gold badge, though).

Answer (score 13):

There are many badges that can be obtained multiple times.  Also, you can get gold tag badges—and the enormous amount of tags means there's also an enormous amount of tag badges.

If you want more gold badges, go and answer questions. That's how to get tag badges, and you can work towards multiple tag badges at the same time. It also can help you get the Nice Answer, Good Answer and Great Answer badges.

Or ask good questions, and get multiple Nice/Good/Great Question badges.